# Sublime Text 3 - Set Default "Plain Text" to Java

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I want the default sublime text 3 file type from "Plain Text" to Java. I tried by installing a package from github (), creating a new default_file_type setting and then setting:

```
{
    "default_new_file_syntax": "Packages/Java.sublime-settings",
    "use_current_file_syntax": true
}
```

But no luck so far. I guess the package works for version 2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it right. The correct setting should be:

```js
{
    "default_new_file_syntax": "Packages/Java/Java.tmLanguage",
    "use_current_file_syntax": true
}
```

You need to assign the path of the actual language syntax file (`.tmLanguage`). Also, in case you weren't aware, the `"use_current_file_syntax"` setting means that if you have a file open with a certain syntax, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to open a new file, that new file will use the syntax of the previously open file, not necessarily Java. If you want **all** new files to have the Java syntax, set `"use_current_file_syntax": false`.